# Process.WaitForExit() triggers too fast

Tags: c#, .net, process

Here is the code I use to run extern executable (unmanaged) from c# code:

```
static void Solve()
            {
                Process newProc = new Process();
                newProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory =  Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data");
                newProc.StartInfo.FileName = "solver.exe";
                newProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                newProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                try
            {
                newProc.Start();
                newProc.WaitForExit();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            StreamWriter errorReporter = new StreamWriter("ErrorLog.txt", true);
    errorReporter.WriteLine(message);
    errorReporter.Close();

            }
            newProc.Close();
        }
```

In my case solver works about 30 seconds if I start it manually. The result of solver.exe actions is a file. But when I call for it from code, it exits almost the same moment and does nothing. No output comes from it, output file is not generated.

Also, process is started correctly, no errors are thrown. Is there any problems in the code above or should I just start with checking solver.exe?

Comment: What happens if you [RedirectStandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried `UseShellExecute = false`

Comment: Seems unlikely that a program called "solver" doesn't need to be told *what* to solve.  Use the StartInfo.Arguments property to pass a command line argument.

Comment: @HansPassant Totally agree :) There are some input files generated before solving, no parameters needed. Thanks for attention.

Comment: If messing around with the ProcessStartInfo won't help, you may need to debug Solver as it executes when launched from your code. A debugger along with logging/tracing at the Solver, plus tools such as Sysinternals Process Explorer, would go a long way. Use Process Explorer to inspect the environment variables and executing directory of the Solver. Use the debugger + logging / tracing to figure out what is going on inside the Solver, if exceptions are thrown, etc.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Did not make any difference. Thanks for attention.

Comment: @rene This was helpful! Thanks a lot, I found a bug using this tool. Problem was in shared file access. Can you please write it down as an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: @M.A.Hanin Solver is fortran-based old school tool, let's consider it's a black box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your process is probably failing in an unforeseen way. You can only know to read the Output and Error stream and store it in a file (or write it to the console, or eventlog)

Remember that if you need to read the Error AND the Output streams simultanuously to do it async/eventdriven. Otherwise the streams will block and not produce any output or not the output you're after.

```
StreamWriter errorReporter = new StreamWriter("SOLVER-OUTPUT-ERROR.txt", true);

newproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
newproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

newproc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => errorReporter.WriteLine(args.Data);
newproc.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => errorReporter.WriteLine(args.Data);
newproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=false;

newProc.Start();
newProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
newProc.BeginErrorReadLine();

newProc.WaitForExit();

errorReporter.Close();
```