# How to run a Powershell script from WCF in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell

I have java application which needs run dynamically through the power shell with my WCF c# application.
I have tried the following  command

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("powershell.exe", strCmd + " ; timeout 50");
```

But still I am unable to succeed could tell me how can I do it

Comment: I haven't got any error but the powershell is not running,which I cannot see in the server.

Comment: The `Start` method returns the Process so you can check the errors from it.

Comment: Capture the output of the command as I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17964760/578411)

Answer (score 1):

There are several Things that could be wrong here:

- Does the WCF service have the required rights to run the PowerShell command?
- Will the PowerShell command be executed in the correct Directory?
- Should the conncatination be done before the start command?

Having said that, this is not a good idea, you are opening Your machine to attackers to run any PowerShell script they want.

Comment: i have my dadicate azure VM and i set all required rights to application. and i am running that form Automation dll but i think that is not working, any idea why powershell commands noto fireing, i am createing new azure website site form my ps1 script.